# Using a loop and saveas to save multiple embedded word documents to C drive (or others)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel sheet with multiple word documents saved in it, and I would like to programatically save them from the excel embedded document to a drive.  I used some code I found here and tried to add a loop for it to go through each document and save, but it errors before the loop completes.  Here is the code:

```
Sub aaSaveEmbedded1()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

i = 1
Do Until i = 10


Dim num As String
num = Cells(i + 9, 4).Value
Dim nam As String
nam = Cells(i + 9, 8).Value & ".doc"
Dim sh1 As Shape
Dim objWord As Object ''Word.Document
Dim objOLE As OLEObject

''The shape holding the object from 'Create from file'

Set sh1 = ActiveSheet.Shapes(i)

''Activate the contents of the object
sh1.OLEFormat.Activate

''The OLE Object contained
Set objOLE = sh1.OLEFormat.Object

''This is the bit that took time
Set objWord = objOLE.Object

''Save it
objWord.SaveAs2 Filename:="C:\Users\rchandler\Desktop\condor project\Procedures\1_Drilling Procedures\" & num & nam, _
FileFormat:= _
wdFormatTemplate  ''1=wdFormatTemplate


objWord.Application.Quit
Set objWord = Nothing
Set sh1 = Nothing
Set objOLE = Nothing
num = Empty
nam = Empty

i = i + 1

Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

When I run the code the first iteration works and the first document is saved.  After that I get a error stating "Cannot start the source application for this object" on this line:

sh1.OLEFormat.Activate

I just started to use VBA this week, and I do not have very much experience programming so any help will be greatly appreciated.  It takes me a long time to fix problems atm.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I created an Excel 2010 document, inserted two Objects of type Word, typed 'Test 1' into the first container  and 'Test 2' into the second and ran your code -- it immediately threw an error because you were activating the OLE object and the SaveAs2 method cannot save something which is being edited.  However, when I commented out the activation, it worked just fine,

I had to change the SaveAs to use i & i instead of num & num in the filename (since I did not have a value populated in the cells you were reading and assigning to the variable num).  Is it possible that your filenames based on num & num are not unique on the second round?  If this is the case it would definately cause the SaveAs2 method call to bomb (if the file already exists).